# How take value from matematic operation as string and modify in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of string into html page with math operation like `["2","*","3","-","1"]`, in html body i have used:

```
<p>{{$eval(expression)}}</p>
```

in js

```
 $scope.math = [];
 $scope.expression = $scope.math.join('');
```

I need to take this value and modify into js, as example
expression + 1 then show 6. i need to take the result 5 and sum to 1
Thanks for answer.

Comment: That sounds interesting, so do it. But why do you need to announce it here? If you have a question, then ask it. Otherwise please don't inform us what are you going to do. This is not Facebook.

Comment: sorry, i have change title

Comment: Thank you. But the _title_ is not a good place for the question. As the name suggests, it should contain the _title_ (summarization of what is the question about in a few words). You have whole question's content for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` in controller as well. For example:

Controller:

```
 $scope.math = ["2","*","3","-","1"];
 $scope.expression = $scope.math.join('');
 $scope.modifiedExpression = eval($scope.expression) + 1;
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{$eval(expression)}}</p>
<p>{{modifiedExpression}}</p>
```

Result:

```
5
6
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xfrjdtrb/

Comment: thanks you have solved my problem